# tdch export utility: Nifi processor

Tags: teradata, apache-nifi

I'm creating a export utility in NiFi to put data from Hive to Teradata. As a prerequisite, I tried using TDCH utility from CLI to test if it's working or not. Giving me some error that I couldn't figure out. Need some extra eye on this to provide insight:

TDCH Export statement:

```
hadoop jar $USERLIBTDCH com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool
       -libjars $LIBJARS
       -url jdbc:teradata://dns.com/DATABASE=dbName
       -username abc
       -password abc
       -jobtype hcat
       -sourcedatabase testing
       -sourcetable emp
       -nummappers 20
       -targettable emp
```

LIBJARS=`hive-metastore-*.jar
hive-exec-*.jar
hive-cli-*.jar
libthrift-*.jar
libfb303-*.jar
jdo2-api-*-ec.jar
slf4j-api-*.jar
datanucleus-core-*.jar
datanucleus-rdbms-*.jar
commons-dbcp-*.jar
commons-pool-*.jar
antlr-runtime-*.jar
datanucleus-api-jdo-*.jar
hcatalog-core-*.jar`

And USERLIBTDCH=`/usr/lib/tdch/1.5/lib/teradata-connector-1.5.3.jar`

The error I'm receiving:

```
INFO tool.ConnectorExportTool: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/CommandNeedRetryException
        at com.teradata.connector.hcat.processor.HCatInputProcessor.inputPreProcessor(HCatInputProcessor.java:50)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorJobRunner.runJob(ConnectorJobRunner.java:118)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool.run(ConnectorExportTool.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool.main(ConnectorExportTool.java:853)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.CommandNeedRetryException
```

For `TDCH`, this error doesn't show any help on google. Does anyone have any pointers for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was due to hadoop setup. I have set the HADOOP_CLASSPATH explicitly (as Java jars only) and while running hive, it need some more hadoop jar files and the same is add through hive configuration file. So we need to set HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop-env.sh as below

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH = ${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:{yours previous classpath}
```

**Reference:**

[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/CommandNeedRetryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151585/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-hiv)

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/47240/hive-install-and-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks Mahendra for the response. Mine is a CDH installation so ideally all the relevant jars are present in single place in parcels; & none of the paths, either HADOOP_HOME, HIVE_HOME, HADOOP_CLASSPATH, etc are set. Looking at your response, I guess the classpath information in my case should be the path to parcels only or should I create a separate area & copy the relevant jars there?

Comment: Yes you can check that with seperate area and copy the jars to there.